# Asp.Net Script for price change works fine in IE, But not in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following `PriceChange` script works fine in Internet Explorer but not in any other browser. Can you please help?

```
case 'A':   document.getElementById("cs_priceinr").value=price;
            if(price<=100)
            {
                document.getElementById("cs_priceusd").value = 2.50;
                document.getElementById("cs_usdair").value = 6.95;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("cs_priceusd").value = Math.round((price/40.00)*100)/100;
                if(price<=250)
                    document.getElementById("cs_usdair").value = Math.round((price/15)*100)/100;
                else if(price<=500)
                    document.getElementById("cs_usdair").value = Math.round((price/16)*100)/100;
                else if(price<=750)
                    document.getElementById("cs_usdair").value = Math.round((price/17)*100)/100;
                else
                    document.getElementById("cs_usdair").value = Math.round((price/18)*100)/100;
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `textContent` or `nodeValue` instead of `value`.

The value property does not seem to be standard:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element